# Я хочу узнать ширину изображения в tkinter, но при image.winfo_width() выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, tkinter

Я решил написать программу. В ней я хочу разместить изображение в центре, но ещё и нужно переместить его на половину ширины влево, чтобы было симметрично. Вот код:

```
...        

class Image:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.image = self.game.canvas.create_image(self.game.width/2, self.game.height/2, image = PhotoImage(file = "img/Character/test.gif"))
        self.width = self.image.winfo_width()
        self.height = self.image.winfo_height()
        self.game.canvas.move(self.image, -self.width/2, -self.height/2)

...
```

При попытке нахождения длины, мне выводит:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'winfo_width'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `create_image` объекта `Canvas` возвращает id созданного объекта (изображения в данном случае) - а это целое число. У целого числа нет метода `winfo_width` - отсюда ошибка.

Чтобы получить размеры объекта можно воспользоваться методом `bbox` - он возвращает координаты левого верхнего и правого нижнего угла ограничивающего прямоугольника (bounding box) объекта на canvas, из этих координат можно получить размеры объекта.

```
x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.game.canvas.bbox(self.image)
self.width = x1 - x0
self.height = y1 - y0
```